# Исключение при работе с файлами

Tags: asp.net, c#, файлы

Работаю с файлом, который был загружен через форму ASP.NET.В строчках возникает исключение

> An exception of type
> 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException'
> occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not
> handled in user code Additional
> information: Файл 'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\IIS Express\Безымянный.png' не
> найден

Код

```
FileInfo f = new FileInfo(file.FileName);
    FileStream stream = f.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

Comment: file.InputStream.Read(array, 0, file.ContentLength);
Так вроде работает. 

А как можно восстановить файл  потока байт?

Answer (score 4):

В вашем случае FileInfo полагает, что файл находится в папке веб-сервера (что в общем-то логично, поскольку сайт запускается  веб-сервером). Чтобы получить корректный путь, вам стоит использовать **Server.MapPath(file.FileName)**

Answer (score -1):

В исключении все сказано: Этого файла по такому пути не существует. Попробуйте избежать русских символов в пути и имени файла.